# Como aplicar um str_replace apenas em termos idênticos?

Tags: php

Criei a função abaixo:

```php
function setFamiliarURLsInsteadOfNames($FamURLsList=array(), $texto){
    if(!is_array($FamURLsList) || empty($FamURLsList))
        return array('error'=>true,'message'=>'$FamURLsList deve conter uma lista válida de Nomes e URLs');
    /* $FamURLsList é um array com os Nomes e URLs para a função abaixo */
    $toSearch = array(); $toChange = array();
    foreach($FamURLsList as $uriData){
        $toSearch[] = htmlentities($uriData["nome"]); /* Array com os Nomes */
        $toChange[] = '@'.$uriData["url"]; /* Array com os @URLs */
    }
    return str_ireplace($toSearch, $toChange, $texto);
}
```

Suponhamos que o meu array `$FamURLsList`, que será passado na função acima, seja o seguinte:

```php
$FamURLsList = array(
    0 => array(
        'url' => 'array-url-1',
        'nome' => 'fico'
    )
);
```

Suponhamos agora que eu tenha a variável `@texto` com o valor `'fico'`. Então eu aplico a função nesta variável e vejo o resultado:

```php
echo setFamiliarURLsInsteadOfNames($FamURLsList,$texto);
/* Exibe: @array-url-1 no lugar de 'fico' */
```

Todavia, se a minha variável `@texto` tivesse o valor `'identifico'`, a saída seria `identi@array-url-1`.

Como eu posso substituir apenas as palavras que forem exatamente iguais ao termo buscado, ignorando quaisquer outros casos em que ele apareça no início, meio ou fim?

Para tentar tornar ainda mais claro, como posso substituir apenas `fico` para `@array-url-1` e nunca substituir `identifico` para `identi@url-array-1` ou `ficou` para `@array-url-1u`?

Comment: Não entendi direito: vc quer que retorne da função uma string? E se a array `$FamURLsList` tiver mais de uma subarray?

Comment: Blz... vc poderia usar um `if` verificando se o texto na array é igual o texto enviado. Mas cuidado com o boundary `\b` do regex, porque em algumas situações ele pode falhar.

Comment: Sim, é para retornar uma string. Funciona da seguinte forma: a array $FamURLsList possui sub-arrays. Dentro de cada sub-array, terá uma combinação de chaves "nome" e "url". Os "nome"'s são buscados no @texto e substituídos pelos "url"'s, independente da quantidade de sub-arrays. Se tiver mais de 1 sub-array, vai fazer a substituição com todos eles seguindo as mesmas regras. Eu consegui fazer quase perfeitamente usando a dica do rapaz abaixo, com expressão regular. Havia uma regra de regex que eu não conhecia e já me resolveu parcialmente :)

Comment: Eu encontrei umas situações em que ele falhou, mas só de já ter essa solução eu consigo ir pesquisando e aprendendo por conta própria a partir de agora. Precisava mais de um norte mesmo pois já havia tentado de tudo e não tinha conseguido ainda.

Comment: A função usa os sub-arrays pra montar os termos de busca e substituição, apenas. Cada sub-array tem um `"nome"` e um `"url"`, que são iterados no `foreach` pra gerar dois novos arrays: um com os termos de busca chamado `$toSearch` e outro com os termos que serão postos no lugar dos antigos chamado `$toChange`. Esses dois arrays são passados no replace em conjunto, pra fazer a busca e a alteração sequencial. Eu poderia fazer tudo num laço de repetição, mas assim consome menos recursos. É um sistema pesado. Você pode ver um exemplo em funcionamento [aqui](http://bit.ly/2PCle84), se quiser.

Comment: E [nesse webservice aqui](https://webservice.tiolou.com.br/icarus-na/put-links/familiares) é montado o array `$FamURLsList`

Comment: E se não achar a palavra, qual string deve retornar?

Comment: Exatamente a original, sem nenhuma modificação. A única coisa que eu faço ali, na verdade, é montar dois arrays com as buscas e substituições, o retorno quem faz é a função `str_ireplace` ou, agora com a modificação, a `preg_replace`. Ambas quando não há alteração, retornam a string original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

No exemplo que você passou é possível utilizar regex para substituir exclusivamente a palavra 'fico' da seguinte forma:

```
preg_replace('/\bfico\b/', '@array-url-1', $texto);
```

E no seu código ficaria:

```
return preg_replace('/\b'.$toSearch.'\b/', $toChange, $texto);
```

Para mais informações sobre \b leia [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Funcionou quase perfeitamente do modo como você pôs ai em cima. Mas em alguns casos o `\b` falhou. Pra ser mais específico, eu poderia lhe mostrar exemplos claros do que houve, em funcionamento (na seção "Descrição" da página). [Aqui um texto 100% funcional, trocando o Nome pelo @URL](https://icarus-na.tiolou.com.br/familiares/grudd) e [aqui um nada funcional](https://icarus-na.tiolou.com.br/familiares/ura). Vou pesquisar mais sobre as Word Boundaries e ver se consigo resolver, mas até lá posso considerar esse código como funcional.